# Pipeline of greps on running process outputs nothing

Tags: linux, macos, pipe

I'm using a macbook, Darwin os.

I have a running process ./r that generates a log file which it runs. It is a long running process.

When I filter once like this, it works and I see all lines except those with 'A' in them.

```
./r | grep -v A
```

But when I do this, there is no output, even though not all lines contain 'B'

```
./r | grep -v A | grep -v B
```

To prove this I can do this, which does indeed show output.

```
./r > tmp
# wait 30 seconds, ctrl-c
cat tmp | grep -v A | grep -v B
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buffering.

When it's in the tmp file and you pipe that in, there is an EOF, which ends the pipeline. But with your running process, that EOF never comes (because process is still running).

Probably there is an environment and/or OS level setting for this, idk... but you can force grep to not buffer more than one line.

Try this.

```
grep --line-buffered -v A
```